# Silverstripe 3.0 hide not allowed children from "add new"

Tags: php, silverstripe

In Silverstripe 3.1.* pages that are not in the $allowed_children array are disabled in the "add new" menu. In Silverstripe 3.0 however, they are still showing. If you want to create a page that is not allowed under the selected parent, you get an orange error notice:

"Page type "MyPage" not allowed as child of this parent page"

How can one hide or disable the not allowed children in Silverstripe 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a 3.0 issue, maybe you can compare 3.1 code and provide a pull request for the 3.0 branch. A dirty workarond that may work for you is to add the following line to your children pages, in order to permit creation of them only to ADMIN.

```
private static $can_create = false;
```